# How can I support wildcards in user-defined search strings in Python?

Tags: python, search, parsing, string, wildcard

Is there a simple way to support wildcards ("*") when searching strings - without using RegEx?

Users are supposed to enter search terms using wildcards, but should not have to deal with the complexity of RegEx:

```
"foo*"   =>  str.startswith("foo")
"*foo"   =>  str.endswith("foo")
"*foo*"  =>  "foo" in str
```

(it gets more complicated when there are multiple search terms though, e.g. "foo*bar*baz")

This seems like a common issue, so I wonder whether there's a ready-made solution for it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For asking normal programming questions, please don't mark your question as "community wiki". Nobody (including you) gets any reputation for that kind of question. I see you're new here, so no worries, just keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: What's wrong with regular exceptions?

Comment: First off, its regular **expressions**.  Second, wouldn't it be easy enough to escape anything in the input that needs escaping for regex, turn `*` into `.*` and run it through the regex module?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try the [`fnmatch`](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-fnmatch.html) module, it's got a shell-like wildcard syntax.