# How can I support * in user-defined search strings in python?

Tags: python, regex

This question is related to this stack overflow question:

[How can I support wildcards in user-defined search strings in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238600/how-can-i-support-wildcards-in-user-defined-search-strings-in-python)

But I need to only support the wildcards and not the ? or the [seq] functionality that you get with fnmatch.  Since there is no way to remove that functionality from fnmatch, is there another way of doing this?

I need a user defined string like this:  `site.*.com/sub/`
to match this: `site.hostname.com/sub/`

Without all the added functionality of ? and []

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could compile a regexp from your search string using split, re.escape, and '^$'.

```
import re
regex = re.compile('^' + '.*'.join(re.escape(foo) for foo in pattern.split('*')) + '$')
```

Comment: This was perfect.  I was trying to figure out a way to escape all the little bits of re, but thought it would be really complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If its just one asterisk and you require the search string to be representing the whole matched string, this works:

```
searchstring = "site.*.com/sub/"
to_match = "site.hostname.com/sub/"

prefix, suffix = searchstring.split("*", 1)

if to_match.startswith(prefix) and to_match.endswith(suffix):
    print "Found a match!"
```

Otherwise, building a regex like [Tobu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043449/how-can-i-support-in-user-defined-search-strings-in-python/2043531#2043531) suggests is probably best.

Comment: Yea, it's user generated so I could be anything.